# Why unit vector function is continuous?

Tags: continuity

I wonder why $\dfrac{x}{\|x\|}$ is a continuous function, $x$ is a vector in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$. I have read in this site that the quotient of two continuous functions is continuous, but in books, there is no theorem that says that in case that we have a scalar valued vector function multiplied by a vector function.

Can anyone tell me the rule I'm missing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is continuous *in its domain*, i.e., in $\Bbb R^n\setminus\{0\}$.

Comment: You can view it component wise and it becomes scalar valued function divided by scalar valued function.

Comment: Each component is a quotient of continuous functions. Maybe not in books this particular result, but it's remarked often the idea of the components as functions $\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$

Comment: Hope [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1735532/is-function-to-unit-vector-is-continuous) helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a first step prove that a vector valued function is continuous if and only if all its components are continuous functions. ( You can see: [Continuity of a vector function through continuity of its components](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/307290/continuity-of-a-vector-function-through-continuity-of-its-components)). Then note that , for any component $x_i$, the function  $\frac{x_i}{||x||}$, for $||x|| \ne 0$ is continuous as a quotient of continuous functions.